# Android SQLite Constraint error

Tags: android, sqlite, constraints

Here is my buggy coding I've created a table called 'details' following is the database code for that table with insert method as 'insertDescription'

```
public void insertDescription(int rid, String name, String phoneno, String email, String subject, String desc){
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("_rid", rid);
    cv.put("name", name);
    cv.put("phoneno", phoneno);
    cv.put("email", email);
    cv.put("subject", subject);
    cv.put("desc", desc);
    Log.d("DB", "Record is here!");
    sdb.insert("details", null, cv);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
arg0.execSQL("CREATE TABLE users ( _uid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, mail TEXT, password TEXT, hint TEXT);");
arg0.execSQL("CREATE TABLE details (_rid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, " +
            "phoneno VARCHAR(10) CONSTRAINT phone CHECK(phoneno LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')," +
" email TEXT, subject TEXT, desc TEXT);");
}
```

Using that above i'm inserting the values to the database by the following java code

```
String rnos = rno.getText().toString();
int rnoz = Integer.parseInt(rnos);
String names = name.getText().toString();
String mobiles = mobile.getText().toString();
String emailids = emailid.getText().toString();
String subjects = subject.getText().toString();
String descs = desc.getText().toString();
String dates = date.getText().toString();
if(rnos.isEmpty() || names.isEmpty() || mobiles.isEmpty()
    || emailids.isEmpty() || subjects.isEmpty()|| descs.isEmpty() || dates.isEmpty()){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "All Fields are Mandatory", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        mdb.openDB();
        mdb.insertDescription(rnoz, names, mobiles, emailids, subjects, descs);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Record Saved Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        mdb.closeDB();
```

Following error occurs. I've no idea to deal with the SQL query I just got this query constraint query from my friend. Anyhow the table created successfully I saw that table structure after the program execution. Following is my error log

```
07-30 22:06:23.215: E/SQLiteDatabase(876): Error inserting desc=uuuu email=uuuu subject=uuuu phoneno=99808 name=uuuu _rid=1234
07-30 22:06:23.215: E/SQLiteDatabase(876): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: constraint failed (code 19)
07-30 22:06:23.215: E/SQLiteDatabase(876):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
07-30 22:06:23.215: E/SQLiteDatabase(876):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:775)
07-30 22:06:23.215: E/SQLiteDatabase(876):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
07-30 22:06:23.215: E/SQLiteDatabase(876):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
07-30 22:06:23.215: E/SQLiteDatabase(876):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
07-30 22:06:23.215: E/SQLiteDatabase(876):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
07-30 22:06:23.215: E/SQLiteDatabase(876):  at in.blogspot.pcnlap.sha_college_guide.MyDataBase.insertDescription(MyDataBase.java:47)
07-30 22:06:23.215: E/SQLiteDatabase(876):  at in.blogspot.pcnlap.sha_college_guide.DescriptionPage.onClick(DescriptionPage.java:51)
07-30 22:06:23.215: E/SQLiteDatabase(876):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 22:06:23.215: E/SQLiteDatabase(876):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-30 22:06:23.215: E/SQLiteDatabase(876):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3593)
07-30 22:06:23.215: E/SQLiteDatabase(876):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4091)
07-30 22:06:23.215: E/SQLiteDatabase(876):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17072)
07-30 22:06:23.215: E/SQLiteDatabase(876):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-30 22:06:23.215: E/SQLiteDatabase(876):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-30 22:06:23.215: E/SQLiteDatabase(876):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
07-30 22:06:23.215: E/SQLiteDatabase(876):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
07-30 22:06:23.215: E/SQLiteDatabase(876):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 22:06:23.215: E/SQLiteDatabase(876):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-30 22:06:23.215: E/SQLiteDatabase(876):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
07-30 22:06:23.215: E/SQLiteDatabase(876):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
07-30 22:06:23.215: E/SQLiteDatabase(876):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I hope the error occurs due to the constraint statement i've given in the query. In that inserting method of the Java 'insertDescription()' i'm trying to save everything as a String. If any better query or Alternatives available suggest me i've given my complete project zip not complete(i'm stucking with the middle of the query) [skydrive](http://sdrv.ms/13WXEEJ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LIKE` does not support character classes.
You get an error because the first character of your phone number is not `[`, or the second isn't `0`, or the third isn't `-`, etc.

Replace `LIKE` with [`GLOB`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like).

Comment: I read the document but I'm newbie to sql or sqlite queries. could you tell me how to insert only phone number(10 digit)in database, this is my requirment. I've tried several query nothing seems like working @CL.

Comment: Like I said, just replace `LIKE` with `GLOB`.

Answer (score 0):

you have problem with   `phoneno VARCHAR(10) CONSTRAINT phone CHECK(phoneno LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')`

in following code

```
arg0.execSQL("CREATE TABLE details (_rid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, " +
            "phoneno VARCHAR(10) CONSTRAINT phone CHECK(phoneno LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')," +
" email TEXT, subject TEXT, desc TEXT);");
```

Comment: what should i do for a fix? @Taresm

Comment: @AkbarShaEbrahim sorry i am not so familiar with your this CONSTRAINT you can try without CONSTRAINT, and apply validations on data while user is entering instead of in database !